# php - Cannot call time() in variable definition in class

Tags: php, oop, properties

I have a class that I need to use php's `time()` function in:

```
<?php
class SomeClass {
    public $expiration = time() + (21 * 24 * 60 * 60); // 3 wks from now  

}
```

However this throws:

> **Parse error**:  syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';' in **[...][...]** on line 5

I can do this and it works:

```
<?php
class SomeClass {
    public $expiration = 0

    function __construct() {
        $this->expiration = time() + (21 * 24 * 60 * 60); 
    }
}
```

Why is it that I can't do it the first way?

Comment: Because `class` is just a description of an object.

Comment: Although this is marked as a dupe, when I searched for it, I had no idea I was searching for "dynamically" defined class properties. I only know I wanted time(). Don't know how I could have foreseen this. I could delete this question and regain some rep, but I think it's worth having here in case anyone else needs to define time() in a class and doesn't land on the duplicated question either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is it that I can't do it the first way?

Because http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php:

> "[properties] are defined by using one of the keywords public, protected, or private, followed by a normal variable declaration. This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a **constant value**--that is, it **must be able to be evaluated at compile time** and **must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated**."

Answer (score 1):

From the PHP documentation for [Properties](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php):

> Class member variables are called "properties". You may also see them referred to using other terms such as "attributes" or "fields", but for the purposes of this reference we will use "properties". They are defined by using one of the keywords public, protected, or private, followed by a normal variable declaration. **This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.**

The call to `time()` would not be a constant value. Thus it is would be invalid.